# Regex that matches numeric with up to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I am after a regex that will match numeric values with up to a user defined number of decimal places. Currently I have

```
/(^-?\d\d*\.\d*$)|(^-?\d\d*$)|(^-?\.\d\d*$)/
```

which will allow as many places as input but I would also like to sometimes allow 2 for currency or 4 or more for other input. The function I am building is

```
var isNumeric = function(val, decimals) {
    // decimals is not used yet
    var objRegExp = /(^-?\d\d*\.\d*$)|(^-?\d\d*$)|(^-?\.\d\d*$)/;
    return objRegExp.test(val);
};
```

Answer (score 25):

```
/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/
```

It's good to be forgiving of whitespace (\s).  The above doesn't allow starting with zero.  If you want to allow that:

```
/^\s*-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/
```

Neither of the above allow a decimal number with nothing before the decimal place.  If you want to allow that:

```
/^\s*-?(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$/
```

Comment: Do you have a variation that allows for a trailing `.` without any digits after it? JavaScript considers this a valid number, as long as there aren't _two_ trailing dots (`isNaN(1.) //false`)

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this:

> `^\d+\.\d{0,3}$`

where "3" is the maximum allowed decimal places.

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers), the quantifier `x{n,m}` requires that "n and m are **positive** integers" – ie, 0 is not a valid lower bound. [But the spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1) that the type of `n` and `m` is `DecimalDigits`, so 0 is allowed. MDN is wrong here: Your expression conforms to the spec and safe to use in any browser.

Answer (score 4):

Adding that 0 if the last digit is a "." doesn't cover the case of whitespace after the dot.

I think this covers all the cases, but you would want to test it a more rigorously than I have here.

```
var isNumeric = function(val, decimals) {
    if (decimals <= 0) {
        var re = /^\s*\d+\.?\s*$/;
        return re.test(val);
    } else {
        var reString = "^\\s*((\\d+(\\.\\d{0," + decimals + "})?)|((\\d*(\\.\\d{1," + decimals + "}))))\\s*$"
        var re = new RegExp(reString);
        return re.test(val);
    }
};

var test = function(val, decimals) {
    document.write("isNumeric(" + val + ", " + decimals + ") = " + isNumeric(val, decimals) + "<br/>");
}

test("123", 0);
test("123", 5);
test(" 123.45", 2);
test(" 123.45", 3);
test(" 123.45", 1);
test(" ", 0);
test(" ", 5);
test(" 3.", 0);
test(" 3.", 12);
test(" .", 3);
test(" .321 ", 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a C# guy by trade, but I find tools like [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) for C# or [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) to be exceedingly helpful when trying to tweak that Regex to be "just so".

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all. I used a bit from all answers.

```
var isNumeric = function(val, decimalPlaces) {
    // If the last digit is a . then add a 0 before testing so if they type 25. it will be accepted
    var lastChar = val.substring(val.length - 1);
    if (lastChar == ".") val = val + "0";

    var objRegExp = new RegExp("^\\s*-?(\\d+(\\.\\d{1," + decimalPlaces + "})?|\\.\\d{1," + decimalPlaces + "})\\s*$", "g");
    if (decimalPlaces == -1)
        objRegExp = new RegExp("^\\s*-?(\\d+(\\.\\d{1,25})?|\\.\\d{1,25})\\s*$", "g");

    return objRegExp.test(val);        
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex, it works fine for me:

```
^\d+\.\d{0,2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

This should match integers and decimals up to two decimal places.

```
/\A[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\z/
```

**NOTE:**  Change the "2" in "{1,2}"to whatever number of decimal places you want to support.

I know this isn't part of your question, but you can do this without a regex too.  Here is one solution:

```
var isNumeric = function( val, decimals ) {
    if ( parseFloat( val ) ) {
        var numeric_string = val + '';
        var parts = numeric_string.split( '.', 1 );
        if ( parts[1] && parts[1].length > decimals ) {
            alert( 'too many decimal places' );
        }
        else {
            alert( 'this works' );
        }
    }
    else {
        alert( 'not a float' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This failed to match on integers or decimals with one or two places using the following syntax:

var regex = new Regex("/\\A[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?\\z/");
if (regex.IsMatch("1234")) {

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
[0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```