# Accept input only number with 2 decimal Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, javascript-framework

I want to make user control to get number like this:

```
125.00
125
125.27
125.20
1231545.25
2566.66
```

I have tried with mask textbox but its length can be anything.
I have used textbox with Javascript that accepts a number
like this:
[click here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox)

If a Javascript plugin is available for this let me know, 
or any code to accept value in price format.

Restrict user to insert only number and two decimal spaces while entering.

If number is not well formatted then cut and format number after text change.

Like if 125.2 then 125.20 or if 125 then 125.00 or 135156. then 135156

I have search on internet but no plugin or script was found for this.

I have a plugin like numeric.js but it doesn't restrict decimal spaces.

Post if any Javascript available.

I don't want to do validation to check for entered values; I want to accept values with restriction.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you seen this : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660682/regex-that-matches-numeric-with-up-to-2-decimal-places**

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Ajax Control Toolkit MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_MaskedEdit.ashx)** control:

**MaskedEdit** is an **ASP.NET AJAX extender that attaches to a TextBox control to restrict the kind of text that can be entered.** MaskedEdit applies a "mask" to the input that permits only certain types of characters/text to be entered. The supported data formats are: Number, Date, Time, and DateTime. MaskedEdit uses the culture settings specified in the CultureName property. If none is specified the culture setting will be the same as the page: English (United States).

Sample Code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender  
    TargetControlID="TextBox2"   
    Mask="9,999,999.99"  
    MessageValidatorTip="true"   
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"   
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"  
    MaskType="Number"   
    InputDirection="RightToLeft"   
    AcceptNegative="Left"   
    DisplayMoney="Left"  
ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"/>
```

[See Working Demo](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I also having same problem.This code has solved my problem.This solution is exactly what u want.It's not only foramt yous decimal number but also will eliminate blank spaces. Try this.As in my condition i was allowing user to enter '+' or '-' so i check for this validation also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkforvalidation() {
            var txtvalue = document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value;
            var leftstr = "";
            var rightstr = "";
            var tempstr = "";
            var operator = "";
            txtvalue = txtvalue.replace(/\s/g, '');
            document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value = txtvalue;
            if (txtvalue.indexOf(".") != -1) {

                leftstr = txtvalue.split(".")[0];
                rightstr = txtvalue.split(".")[1];
                if (leftstr.indexOf("-") == 0 || leftstr.indexOf("+") == 0) {

                    operator = leftstr.substr(0, 1);
                    tempstr = leftstr.substr(1, leftstr.length - 1);

                    leftstr = ltrim(tempstr, '0');

                    if (leftstr.length == 0) {
                        leftstr = '0';
                    }

                    if (rightstr.indexOf("-") == -1 || rightstr.indexOf("+") == -1) {

                        rightstr = ltrim(rightstr, '0');

                        rightstr = chkdecimalpoints(rightstr);
                        if (operator != null || operator != "") {
                            txtvalue = operator + leftstr + "." + rightstr;
                        }
                        else {
                            txtvalue = leftstr + "." + rightstr;
                        }
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value = txtvalue;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value = "";
                    }
                }
                else {

                    tempstr = leftstr.substr(0, leftstr.length);
                    leftstr = ltrim(tempstr, '0');
                    if (leftstr.length == 0) {
                        leftstr = '0';
                    }
                    if (rightstr.indexOf("-") == -1 || rightstr.indexOf("+") == -1) {

                        rightstr = rtrim(rightstr, '0');
                        rightstr = chkdecimalpoints(rightstr);
                        txtvalue = leftstr + "." + rightstr;
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value = txtvalue;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (txtvalue.indexOf("-") == -1 || txtvalue.indexOf("+") == -1) {

                txtvalue = ltrim(txtvalue, '0');
                if (txtvalue.length == 0) {
                    txtvalue = '0';
                }
                if (operator != null || operator != "") {
                    txtvalue = operator + txtvalue + ".00";
                }
                // txtvalue = leftstr + "." + rightstr;
                document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value = txtvalue;
            }
            else if (txtvalue.indexOf("-") == 0 || txtvalue.indexOf("+") == 0) {

                operator = txtvalue.substr(0, 1);
                tempstr = txtvalue.substr(1, leftstr.length - 1);
                txtvalue = alltrim(tempstr, '0');
                if (operator != null || operator != "") {
                    txtvalue = operator + txtvalue + ".00";
                    document.getElementById('<%=txtspherical.ClientID %>').value = txtvalue;
                }
            }
        }

        function chkdecimalpoints(rightstr) {
            if (rightstr.length == 0) {
                rightstr = '00';

                return rightstr;

            }
            else if (rightstr.length == 1) {
                rightstr = rightstr + '0';
                return rightstr;
            }
            else if (rightstr.length > 2) {

                var tempvar = rightstr.substr(2, 1);

                if (tempvar >= 5) {

                    tempvar = parseInt(rightstr.substr(1, 1)) + 1;
                    tempvar = rightstr.substr(0, 1) + tempvar.toString();
                    if (tempvar.length > 2) {
                        tempvar = tempvar.substr(0, 2);
                    }
                    return tempvar;
                }
                else {

                    tempvar = rightstr.substr(0, 2);
                    return tempvar;
                }
            }
            else {
                return rightstr;
            }
        }
        function ltrim(str, chars) {
            chars = chars || "\\s";
            return str.replace(new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+", "g"), "");
        }
        function rtrim(str, chars) {
            chars = chars || "\\s";
            return str.replace(new RegExp("[" + chars + "]+$", "g"), "");
        }
        function alltrim(str, chars) {
            chars = chars || "\\s";
            return str.replace(new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+$", "g"), "");
        }

    </script>
```

HTML Source:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtspherical" runat="server" OnBlur="javascript:checkforvalidation();">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validNumber(input){
    input=input.replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if( input.match(/\d+\.*\d*/i) ){
        input=input.match(/(\d+\.*\d*)/i)[1].replace(/\.$/i, "");
        if(!input.match(/\./i)) input+=".00";
        if(input.match(/\.(\d+)/i)[1].length<2) input+="0";
        return input;
    }else{
        return "0.00";
    }
}
```